# Recording children’s voices during filming

Tags: microphone

I’m filming a teacher talking to 10 children seated in front of him. I have a Rode mic on the camera and also a ZoomH6 device, but still not good enough. Are there some hand gel mics I could attach to the H6 that the kids could pass around? Any other suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shotgun overhead on a boom is the way to go with something like this.

Rules of thumb working with kids - never give them anything they can hold, and never use wireless lavaliers.

Take the rode mic off the camera and put it on a boom stand and cable it back to the camera. Keep it high enough so that it remains out of shot.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The overhead boom is not possible due to resource limitations. I film on my own. Any other microphones I can plug I to my ZOOM H6? It can take up to 4 mics. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the Manfrotto 420B stand, or use a C-Stand with a boom-buddy and a boom-pole. This sort of setup does not need a boom operator if you are a solo operator.

Comment: PS I do this all the time.

Comment: Hi Mark, what sort of C stand do you use? I got a boom pole but it’s heavy and I’m worried the stand will tip over.

Comment: I actually use a separate stand with a knuckle that holds a boom-buddy. You just need to get a couple of 5Kg lead weight bags to put on the base of the stand. That will keep it from toppling over.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Have you got a link to one you use?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com.au/Neewer%C2%AE-Microphone-Boompole-Support-Holder/dp/B00YEEDJF6/ref=asc_df_B00YEEDJF6/?tag=googleshopdsk-22&linkCode=df0&hvadid=341792992280&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2783381336940974222&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9071368&hvtargid=pla-363928523937&psc=1

Comment: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/243966-REG/Avenger_A2030DKIT_A2030D_Turtle_Base_Century.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAob3vBRAUEiwAIbs5TnlGcSUAd5KtB0QFlGjXScpgoPOS7uCPgqS6zU4Yj55Ixk-X0GqtuxoC1R8QAvD_BwE&pcur=AUD